# root actionscript 3.0 for flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

When i test my movie, there is a report problem like this "error #1006 clear is not function.

The script that I use is this

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, Setting_awal);  
function Setting_awal(e:MouseEvent):void

{
    Xo = bola.x;
    Yo = bola.y;
    txt_Dx.text = "ΔX = "+(target.x-bola.x)/100+" m";
    txt_Dy.text = "ΔY = "+(bola.y-target.y)/100+" m";
    karet1.x = Xo-10;
    karet1.y = Yo;
    karet2.x = Xo+10;
    karet2.y = Yo;
    MovieClip(root).karet1.clear();
    MovieClip(root).karet1.lineStyle(15, 0x003300, 100);
    MovieClip(root).karet1.moveTo(0, 0);
    MovieClip(root).karet1.lineTo(-2, 0);
    MovieClip(root).karet2.clear();
    MovieClip(root).karet2.lineStyle(15, 0x005500, 100);
    MovieClip(root).karet2.moveTo(0, 0);
    MovieClip(root).karet2.lineTo(-15, 0);

    mc_var.x = 100000;

}
```

Can you show me the wrong point of mycode, please.

Answer (score 3):

replace `karet1`  with `karet1.graphics`

```
MovieClip(root).karet1.graphics.clear();
MovieClip(root).karet1.graphics.lineStyle(15, 0x003300, 100);
MovieClip(root).karet1.graphics.moveTo(0, 0);
MovieClip(root).karet1.graphics.lineTo(-2, 0);
.
.
.
```

take a look at [this article](http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/792/1/Drawing-Shapes-with-AS3/Page1.html) & [adobe site](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html)

then you will find that "clear is not function of karet1" but its a member function of `Graphic` class, and each `karet1` has its own `Graphic` which is accessible trough `karet1.graphics`